# how to connect to postgresql on Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have deployed my [crunchy db](https://github.com/CrunchyData/crunchy-containers/tree/master/examples/kubehelm/crunchy-postgresql-cluster) postgresq on my Kubernetes cluster.

However, I am not sure how to connect to the database remotely.

What command can I use to connect remotely so I can create a new database?

Is there a kubectl command to go with psql?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to look at another forum and found what I needed.  I executed with the pod name and gets me to a bash prompt.

```
kubectl exec -it  <POD_NAME> bash
```

Answer (score 3):

```
kubctl get pods
kubectl exec -it  <POD_NAME> bash
su postgres
psql
```

in the above **postgres** is user name.
you will get:

```
postgres=#
```